# Display value of buttons inside text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[please refer this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chethu1003/L2y2d/810/)

```js
$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});
$("#opener").click(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>dialog demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
  <div id="dialog" title="Phone Number">
    <input type="button" value="1">
    <input type="button" value="2">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="3"><br />
    <input type="button" value="4">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="5">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="6"><br />
    <input type="button" value="7">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="8">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="9"><br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="0">
  </div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="phone number">

</body>

</html>
```

> In this fiddle link if i click on every button number its value should reflect on text field how to do it?? any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});

$( '#dialog input').click (function() {
$("#phone").val( $("#phone").val() + $(this).val());
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you change two things. First give your phone number field the id 'phone', like so:

```
<input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="phone number">
```

Secondly, add a script that adds the value of the pressed button to the value of your input, like so:

```
$( '#dialog input').click (function() {
    $("#phone").val( $("#phone").val() + $(this).val());
})
```

See also: https://jsfiddle.net/52ec3nzn/7/, or use this inline script to test the solution:

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
  $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });

  $( '#dialog input').click (function() {
    $("#phone").val( $("#phone").val() + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>dialog demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Phone Number">
  <input type="button" value="1">
       <input type="button" value="2">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="3"><br />
       <input type="button" value="4">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="5">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="6"><br />
       <input type="button" value="7">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="8">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="9"><br />
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="0">
</div>
<input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="phone number">
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the even for popup buttons and then append it back to your initial input. http://jsfiddle.net/L2y2d/822/

```
$('#dialog input').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
  var oldValue = $('.input').val();

  var newValue = oldValue + value;

  $('.input').val(newValue);
});
```

Comment: This might work for now... but classes are not meant to be used as identifiers/pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this with `jquery`

```
$("button class here").click(function(){
    var num = $(this).attr("value")
    $(your target input text here).append(num)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$( "#dialog" ).on('click','input[type="button"]',function()
{
   var $phone = $('input[type="text"]').val()+''+this.value;
   $('input[type="text"]').val($phone);
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>dialog demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Phone Number">
  <input type="button" value="1">
       <input type="button" value="2">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="3"><br />
       <input type="button" value="4">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="5">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="6"><br />
       <input type="button" value="7">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="8">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="9"><br />
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="0">
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="phone number">
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the click event for input elements like this:

```
$("input").click(function(){alert(this.value)});
```